# Wordpress, out first part of a post, then output second part of a post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently using advanced custom fields relationship fields to out a post no problem.  However, I need to run through two posts at time.  By that I mean, load the first part of the first two posts, then load the second part of the first two posts and so on. First two parts of post 3 and 4, second part of post 3 and 4.

```
<?php 
            $i = 0; 
            $posts = get_field('projects');

            if( $posts ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $posts as $post): 
                      $i++ ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h3>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                     <section>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    <?php if( $i == 2): $i = 0; ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

The output would be something along the lines of this:

```
<div></div>//part 1 first post
<div></div>//part 1 2nd post
<section></section>//part 2 first post
<section></section>//part 2 2nd post
<div></div>//part 1 third post
<div></div>//part 1 fourth post
<section></section>//part 2 third post
<section></section>//part 2 fourth post
```

and so on.

Comment: ACF?  Am I the only person highly offended by the use of unexplained abbreviations?  Ok to use 'em, but please Explain Mystery Abbreviations When First Used (EMAWFU)  thanks,

Comment: @zipzit advanced custom fields

Comment: Better but still not good enough... Is that Advanced Custom Fields Plugin from advancedcustomfields.com, or did you write your own code?  And if you wrote your own, isn't the codex command get_field_id().  Also, its not clear how you divide a post into part 1 and part 2?  Is part one the title and thumbnail, with part2 being the content?  Or is this a page 1, content continued on page 2 issue ?  (have you played with the `<!--more-->` thing yet? )

Comment: Oops. okay I see.. part 1 = divs   part 2 = section.  Apologies..

Comment: @zipzit yes its Advanced Custom Fields Plugin from advancedcustomfields.com.  ACF is almost irrelevant in the question I guess it just happens to be what I'm using. But yes, it would be outputting 2 posts at time, and outputting those into parts.  Divs and sections, then the next 2 posts and so forth

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't exactly what you want but it should get you close to the ballpark?

```
<?php 
     $i = 0; 
     $posts = get_field('projects');
     $temp_string_top = "";
     $temp_string_bottom = "";
     $output_string = "";

     if( $posts ): 
         foreach( $posts as $post): 
             $i++;
             setup_postdata($post);

             $temp_string_top += '<div class="col-sm-6"><h3>'.the_title().'</h3></div>';
             $temp_string_bottom += '<section><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6">';
             $temp_string_bottom += the_post_thumbnail().'</div><div class="col-sm-6">'.the_title().'</div></div></div></section>';

              if( $i == 2){
                    $i = 0;
                    $output_string += $temp_string_top;
                    $output_string += $temp_string_bottom;
                    $output_string += '<div class="clear"></div>';
                    $temp_string_top = "";
                    $temp_string_bottom = "";
              }
          endforeach;
          wp_reset_postdata(); 
       endif;

       echo $output_string;   // oops.. almost forgot this!
?>
```

I didn't test this but I'm pretty sure it will work for you..